# regular expression that has a Or condition?

Tags: java, regex

is it possible to create a OR condition in a regular expression.

i am trying to locate a match that contains a list of file names of this type of pattern

1st  case

```
xxxxx-hello.file
```

or
2nd case

```
xxxx-hello-unasigned.file
```

this reg  > `-hello.file` works fine for the first case but is their a way to check the second case too?

i do not want to create two regex and want to combine the two cases if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Make the group optional:

```
.*-hello(-unasigned)?[.]file
```

---

If performance is an issue, you should set that group as a non-capturing group:

```
.*-hello(?:-unasigned)?[.]file
```

---

If you want it to only match that exact amount of characters, you should use a pipe for your OR case:

```
.{5}-hello[.]file|.{4}-hello-unasigned[.]file
```

Comment: To avoid the ugliness of multiple backslashes, I tend to use `[.]` to match dots.

Comment: @NullUserException - I find `\.` to be cleaner than `[.]`, but that's just me. To each their own I guess.

Comment: But in Java you'd need to use `\\.`

Comment: If you're also using capturing groups, you might want to use a non-capturing group for the optional group: `(?:-unassigned)?`

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - True, but this way is clearer. If performance is a *big* concern, you're right.

Comment: @NullUserException - True. I missed the fact that the question is tagged with [tag:java]. Updated.

Comment: @JosephSilber I see it more like a practical consideration. When you write a long expression capturing a lot of groups, you don't want to be confused by captured groups which don't actually needed to be captured.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens - I added it as a recommendation.

Comment: It does not seem to work/ i forgot to add that this is for a ant script that builds a java project :(

Answer (score 0):

Just use `|`:

```
.*-hello.file|.*-hello-unasigned.file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*-hello.file|*-hello-unassigned.file
```

Use |

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this myself using multiple include in a fileset.

this did the trick for me. no idea why the reg ex diddnt work.

```
<fileset dir="bin" >
                <include name="welcome-hello-unasigned.file" />
                <include name="welcome-hello.file" />
            </fileset>
```